# How to prove $A$ is equivalent to $B$?

Tags: proof-explanation

I know that to prove $A$ is equivalent to $B$, I have to assume $A$ then prove $B$ and then assume $B$ and prove $A$. But let’s say that $C$ is a axiom. Can I use $C$ in my proof of $B$ from $A$ and vice versa? Or can I only use $A$ and $B$, and not $C$?

Edit: I can only prove $(A \land C) \equiv (B\land C)$. Is there any way to prove $A \equiv B$? Remember $C$ is an axiom.

Comment: I think I’m not clear enough. I can only prove $(A \land C) \equiv (B \land C$). Does that mean $A \equiv B$?

Comment: If $C$ is an axiom, it is taken as true, so it can be used for any proof.

Comment: Can you show your proof that $(A\land C)\equiv (B\land C)$?  You said you can prove that.  How so?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are just placeholders for longer statements.

Comment: You can start with $A, C$, to try to prove $B$.  But that gets you only $A\land C$.  If you start with $B, C$ to try to prove A, that gets you only $B \land C$.  How do you prove therefore $A\land C \equiv B\land C$, unless that's given?  I am sorry, but there is not enough information in your post.

Comment: If A is a tautology, and B a contradiction, while C is an axiom, then we will never have $A\land C \equiv B\land C$.  However, regardless of the truth values of $A, B$, if C is an axiom, then $A \lor C \equiv B\lor C$.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are definitely not tautologies, or contradictions. I managed to prove $A \land C \rightarrow B$. This implies $A \land C \rightarrow B \land C$. I also managed to prove $B \land C \rightarrow A$, and thus $B \land C \rightarrow A \land C$. So $A \land C \equiv B \land C$.

Comment: Anyways, I realised that $\bigl( (A \land C) \equiv (B \land C) \bigr) \land C \rightarrow (A \equiv B)$. Since $C$ is an axiom, and I proved $(A \land C) \equiv (B \land C)$, therefore $A \equiv B$ is true.